# typo3 - image - objectStorage - FAL - Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, fal

I want to add image upload in page settings. 
Backend is working as it should (at least I think it is)
Uplaod form shown and working in BE, image data gets written in DB as I think it should (filled added field in pages table (1), filled record in sys_file, sys_file_reference and id's looks correctly connected.

But I don't know how to get that in frontend (fluid) 
I believe the problem might be not getting in the model(whatever I do in constructor, nothing changes/happens).

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/z3V89tqN

Answer (score 0):

Create Files ext_tables.sql and ext_tables.php inside your parkside_pimper Extension.

And use Below Code.

Here Is your Solution: http://pastebin.com/YnEUV9Zz

Where entryLevel = 0 In DropdownNavigation Partial.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant, but it works =) ... so Ill use that. THANKS!